# YouTube Playlist Thumbnail Image issue using YouTube Data API

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I am using the YouTube  Data API to get playlist Title and Thumbnail . 
I am getting the Title easily with this mentioned code but not getting the Thumbnail . Its giving a Null Object response .

I have used this Asyntask to get the response :

```
    new GetPlaylistTitlesAsyncTask(mYouTubeDataApi) {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(PlaylistListResponse playlistListResponse) {
            // if we didn't receive a response for the playlist titles, then there's nothing to update
            if (playlistListResponse == null)
                return;

            mPlaylistTitles = new ArrayList();
            for (com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Playlist playlist : playlistListResponse.getItems()) {
                mPlaylistTitles.add(playlist.getSnippet().getTitle());

                Log.e("Titile", "" + "" + playlist.getSnippet().getTitle());
                Log.e("Thumbnail", "" + "" + playlist.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getDefault().getUrl());
            }
        }
    }.execute(mPlaylistIds);
```

Getting the Playlist Title properly but Video thumbnail is crashing the Application . Need immediate assistance .